# QT shared library using visual studio 2013 addin, how to update text on push button pressed using external wrapper

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013

Directory structure of my project is:

```
QtProject:
    Form Files -> mainInterface.ui     // Directory structure          
    Generated Files -> ui_mainInterface.h   // Directory structure
    Header Files -> QTMainUI.h  // Directory structure
                 -> qtmainui_global.h  // Directory structure
    Source Files -> QTMainUI.cpp   // Directory structure

//Wrapper to execute or get callback from QT shared library  
testWrapperMain:
        Source Files -> testWtrapperMain.cpp
```

**testWtrapperMain.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *widget = new QMainWindow;
    ui.setupUi(widget);
    widget->show();
    app.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

ui_mainInterface.h is created by QT designer tool which all changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file.

**ui_mainInterface.h**

```
class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QWidget *centralwidget;
    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QPushButton *pushButton_2;
    QTextBrowser *textBrowser;
    QMenuBar *menubar;
    QStatusBar *statusbar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(640, 417);
        centralwidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralwidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralwidget"));
        pushButton = new QPushButton(centralwidget);
        pushButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));
        pushButton->setGeometry(QRect(60, 60, 111, 31));
        pushButton_2 = new QPushButton(centralwidget);
        pushButton_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton_2"));
        pushButton_2->setGeometry(QRect(230, 60, 111, 31));
        textBrowser = new QTextBrowser(centralwidget);
        textBrowser->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("textBrowser"));
        textBrowser->setGeometry(QRect(40, 120, 551, 211));
        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);
        menubar = new QMenuBar(MainWindow);
        menubar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menubar"));
        menubar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 640, 21));
        MainWindow->setMenuBar(menubar);
        statusbar = new QStatusBar(MainWindow);
        statusbar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("statusbar"));
        MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusbar);

        retranslateUi(MainWindow);
        QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), MainWindow, SLOT(play()));
        QObject::connect(pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), MainWindow, SLOT(play()));

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", 0));
        pushButton->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "CHECK STATUS", 0));
        pushButton_2->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "REGISTRATION", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui
```

//This file is for getting slots (Callback)
**QTMainUi.h**

```
Ui::MainWindow ui;

class QTMAINUI_EXPORT QTMainUI :public Ui_MainWindow, public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QTMainUI();

    public slots:
    void play(){
        cout << "\n CLicked";
    }
};
```

When we run testWrapperMain.exe file that gives an error on consol i.e.

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QMainWindow::play() in e:\qtmanagementclient\qtma
inui\qtmainui\generatedfiles\ui_maininterface.h:62
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
QObject::connect: No such slot QMainWindow::play() in e:\qtmanagementclient\qtma
inui\qtmainui\generatedfiles\ui_maininterface.h:63
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton_2')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

Actual problem is how to get callback or slot in test wrapper ?

Is there is any alternative approach apart from slots to do this task.

My requirement is I will be having push buttons and text browser. I have created shared library with it, On pressing button from different application, I want to display some text on text browser. I cannot change my application but think of creating gui as dll and On push button call I will display text.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(play()));
```

replacing `MainWindow` with `this` as you are accessing the SLOT of an object.

Comment: while passing this, we are getting error.no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list. Third parameter is Ui_MainWindow *.

Comment: What variable is assigned to the `QtMainUI`?

Comment: hi WLGfx thanks for your comment. Passing this instead of

Comment: hi WLGfx thanks for your valuable comment. Passing this instead of MainWindow it works. But my problem is that  I want when any pushButton is pressed  & slot function (play()) is called at that time it give some any event or notification which button is clicked to my main function which is in testWtrapperMain.cpp, so please provide me any mechanism.

Comment: The quickest way for knowing which button is pressed is to have a slot for each button. Apart from that, you could extend the QPushButton class and store extra information in there.

Comment: Actually when I put play() function definition in ui_mainInterface.h instead of QTMainUi.h. but don't know how to send notification in test Wrapper main.cpp because it is seperate project. And from there I want to set data in textbrowser when any Pushbutton is clicked. Can u elobrate properly with respect of above code.

Comment: Each object that extends `QObject` can have signals and slots in them such as the `QPushButton` which `emit`s a signal which can be connected to a matching `slot` of another object. You can connect multiple `signals` to an objects `slots. Apart from seeing more code from your test module, the best way to understand signals and slots is from http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_SignalsSlotsGui.php